# Laravel: using Javascript inside blade @if

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, if-statement, laravel-blade

I was wondering. It's not possible to put Javascript inside blade @if right? Is blade @if some form of php but using php code will be discouraged in view right? What should I do? Here's the logic of what I'm trying to achieve. Basically, what alternative ways are there to achieve what I'm trying to do? I'm trying to show button when the three conditions are met.

```
@if(isToday($one_parking_info->booking_data->m_bkl_end_date) && isBeforeElevenPM() && notEndInT($one_parking_info->booking_data->m_plots_address_city))
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick="cancelBooking('{{ $one_parking_info->booking_data->m_bkl_gov_id }}')">取消</button>
@endif
```

Comment: Sorry, It's not quite clear that what you want to achieve. May be you can add what error that you get with your code above. Before going through, things we need to understand is what code will executed by server (which is @blade, php), and what code will executed by the browser (javascript).

Comment: What's, exactly, the problem? Your code seems to be OK?! In other words, if the `@if` condition is evaluated true, in your page HTML source you will see, `<button ... onClick="cancelBooking('someIDvalue')">...</button>`

Comment: I'm trying to show button when the three conditions are met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blade is a form of php, so all work is done on the server. So you cannot call javascript functions inside `@if` expression. Instead you can run the functions in the controller and return a value to say if you should include the button or not or you can have a javascript to show or hide the button if you don't care if the users can find and show the button if they want.

Something like in your controller `return view('your view')->with(['showButton' => $shouldShow)` and in your view `@if($shouldShow)` and the rest of your code

Comment: Another complexity is that I have several of this kind of button for different parking info entries. And I'm trying to determine whether I want to show button for each entry.

Comment: You can still do that in the controller and return more parameters or return an array with which buttons to show. @if($showButtons['thisButton']) to keep the business logic in your controller

Comment: Many thanks for insight. I think I've got it. Something along the lines of using associative array via unique key to hold boolean and reading it in the view to determine whether to show button or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your js must be in public or a child, and would be something like this:

```
@if(isToday($one_parking_info->booking_data->m_bkl_end_date) && isBeforeElevenPM() && notEndInT($one_parking_info->booking_data->m_plots_address_city))
    @include('script.js')
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick="cancelBooking('{{ $one_parking_info->booking_data->m_bkl_gov_id }}')">取消</button>
@endif
```

Another option could be `<script src="{{ asset('js/scripts.js') }}"></script>` instead of `@include` directive

Answer (score 0):

i guess:

```
@if(isToday($one_parking_info->booking_data->m_bkl_end_date) && isBeforeElevenPM() && notEndInT($one_parking_info->booking_data->m_plots_address_city))
    @include('script.js')
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-id="{{ $one_parking_info->booking_data->m_bkl_gov_id }}">取消</button>
@endif

<script>
  $('body').on('click','.btn-sm',function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        //
          logic of cancelBooking
        //
   })
</script>
```